# Accessing individual parts of php array

Tags: php, arrays

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) and ($counter < $max)){
    $data[$row['order_id'] . $row['ship_to_name'] .
    $row['shipping_address'] . $row['billing_address'].
    $row['total_paid_incl_vat'] . $row['total_paid_excl_vat'].
    $row['base_shipping_incl_tax']][] = $row['name'] . ' €' . $row['base_row_total_incl_tax'];
```

How can I access $row['order_id'] when looping through it like

```
foreach ($data as $group_title => $groups) {
```

When using echo $group_title; it just echoes out everything but I would like to access the single values.

Thanks!

Comment: "*it just echoes out everything*" Can you elaborate on what your expectation was? You're concatenating all these values together, which would mean this is expected behavior. It seems you might need to re-visit your understanding of PHP data structures, and opt to use something a bit more complex than what you've got here (specifically [Objects](https://www.php.net/object))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you are really looking to do is

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) and ($counter < $max)){
    // create or fix the $row['name']
    $row['name'] = ' €' . $row['base_row_total_incl_tax'];
    // add the row to the array indexed by `order_id`
    $data[$row['order_id']] = $row;
}
```

Now you can

```
foreach ($data as $id => $theRow) {
    echo "Order id  = $id<br>";
    echo "The Address is $theRow[shipping_address]<br>";
    // etc
```